# How to select neighbor element in jquery (or javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML code like this:

```
<tr id="15">
    <td id="NV">1</td>
    <td class="hidden-mob">
        <a href="page.php"><i id="c-voteup" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>
    </td>
<tr>

<tr id="16">
    <td id="NV">1</td>
    <td class="hidden-mob">
        <a href="page.php"><i id="c-voteup" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>
    </td>
<tr>
```

Now I want to increase the value of the first `<td>` in which `<tr>` I click on its `<i>` (neighbor `<td>`).

**For example:** If I click of `<i>` where `<tr id="15">` then I want to increase the value of its `<td>` like this: `<td id="NV">2</td>`. Is it possible ?

Here is my try: I can not implement it fully, just I know about it scatteredly ...

```
$("i").click(function(e) {}                            // when click on <i>

var value =  $("#NV").text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');   // getting current value

value++;                                              // increase its value

$("#NV").html(value);                                 // writing new value
```

Just my problem is *selecting*, How to select `$("#NV")` that I've clicked on `<i>` in the same `<tr>` ?

Comment: .sibling() in jQuery.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz thanks, I read about it, I think it can be useful for my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("i").click(function (e) { // when click on <i>

    var $nv = $(this).closest('tr').find(".NV");
    var value = $nv.text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); // getting current value

    value++; // increase its value

    $nv.html(value);

});
```

- Please change all `#NV` ids to class as IDs are supposed to be unique in DOM.

Comment: thanks, just *jquery-1.8.2.min.js* supports `closest('tr')` ?

Comment: Yup, it is still supported by 1.8.2 only `.closest( selectors [, context ] )` signature (only!) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.8

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).closest('td').prev()` to locate the `td` of interest. However, you must not use duplicate IDs.

```
$('a > i').on('click', function(e) {
    //prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();
    //locate the TD with value   
    var valTD = $(this).closest('td').prev();
    //increment it's value
    valTD.text( +valTD.text() + 1 );
});
```

```js
$('a > i').on('click', function(e) {
    //prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();
    //locate the TD with value   
    var valTD = $(this).closest('td').prev();
    //increment it's value
    valTD.text( +valTD.text() + 1 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tbody>
  <tr id="15">
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="hidden-mob">
        <a href="page.php"><i class="fa fa-caret-up">x</i></a>
    </td>
<tr>

<tr id="16">
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="hidden-mob">
        <a href="page.php"><i class="fa fa-caret-up">x</i></a>
    </td>
<tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why did you use `<tbody>` for table's elements? Totally when should I use `<tbody>` ?

Comment: Glad I could be of help; the pleasure is all mine. ...It is usually better to add these tags explicitly instead of depending on the browser to add them. The main content goes in `tbody`, any headers go in `thead` while any footers you may have go in `tfoot`. See [`tbody`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)